# How to transform a string to a Definition of an Object

Tags: c#, .net, xna, monogame

I want to avoid copy/pasting 4 times the same operation with only changing the byte (`x0.R` to `x0.G` and so for each color).
I'm not sure if it's possible in C# (.NET 3) but I know something similar exists in different languages (ruby with the method `"something".to_sym`).

My code here has a local method `Blend(string color)`. `x0` and `x1` are `Color` objects which return a byte when I call `x0.R` corresponding to red, `x0.G` for green, etc.
I am trying to make it possible for `x0.color` to work, where `color` is a string that can be either `"R"`, `"G"`, `"B"`, or `"A"`.

Is there a way in C# to transform `x0."R"` to `x0.R`?

```
private static Color Interpolate(Color x0, Color x1, float alpha)
    {
        float Blend(string color)
        {
            float z = (float) x0.color / 255 * (1- alpha) + alpha * (float) x1.color / 255; 
            return z;
        }
        // float r = (float) x0.R / 255 * (1- alpha) + alpha * (float) x1.R / 255;
        

        return new Color(Blend("R"),Blend("G"),Blend("B"),Blend("A"));
    }
```

EDIT : I found a method doing exactly what I wrote from the Object `Color` (Xna, not System.Drawings) which is to interpolate 2 colors :

```
private static Color Interpolate(Color x0, Color x1, float alpha)
{
    return Color.Lerp(x0,x1,alpha);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the closest you'll get is something like this:

```
private static Color Interpolate(Color x0, Color x1, float alpha)
{
    float Blend(Func<Color, byte> componentSelector)
    {
        float z = (float) componentSelector(x0) / 255 * (1 - alpha)
            + alpha * (float) componentSelector(x1) / 255; 
        return z;
    }

    return new Color(
        Blend(x => x.R),
        Blend(x => x.G),
        Blend(x => x.B),
        Blend(x => x.A));
}
```

At least I don't know of a shorter form of a delegate to select a property. It would be nice with something like `Blend(_.R)`.

So I think that's your best option unless you want to start doing some reflection, but that's adding complexity for very little gain.

Comment: Okay thanks. I see it's not easier nor shorter. I think I'll stick with my copy/pasting.